# C# End of thread life cycle.

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have several threads, all doing file operations(appending) to several files. every thread writes to ONE file, taking the data from a ConcurrentQueue. A while loop with the condition !queue.empty ensures, that the queue is completly processed.

what happens to the thread when the end condition of the loop is reached eg the delegate method "returns". do they reach a certain state, notifying the garbage collector to collect the object, or to they stay alive in memory, as long as the program is running thus i need to kill them manually?

i'm currently not holding any reference to the thread objects, since my assumption was thread finished, thread gets collected.

is there a way to show how many threads are currently alive?

Answer (score 1):

To check the number of threads running in your application

`Task Manager => Details => Right Click => Select Column => Threads` and check the row containing your `exe`

These might include GC Thread, finalizer thread and others (VS Debug Threads if it is attached)

**You don't need to Kill the thread yourself when it is done**. However, you can check if the thread has completed its work using the `IsAlive` Property.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Your comment sounds like haiku poetry and doesn't make sense to me. Do you think you could rewrite?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I made that statement more explicit in that question update just now.

Comment: @user3185569 - Where did you get the idea that "The thread object might be collected before the thread's work is done"?

Comment: @Enigmativity I think marked for garbage collection was a statement I intended. If the variable is out of scope and not referenced anywhere, it is marked for GC.

Comment: @user3185569 - Threads always have at least one reference (`Thread.CurrentThread`) so they can never be GC'ed early.

Answer (score 0):

A thread terminates when the current function (and the whole call tree that recursively called the current function) terminates.

E.g.

```
void main()
{ 
   Thread thread = new Thread(f);
}

void f()
{
   // allocate suff here  
   g();
}

void g()
{
   // allocate stuff here also
}
```

Thread **thread** completes when **f()** completes. The objects allocated in **f** and **g** are not reachable (if they are local to those functions only) and will be GCed when the CLR wants to.

Comment: You're saying the right thing, but the way you've said it is confusing. I initially thought you meant that the threads don't terminate until the calling thread does. I had to read your answer several times to understand it clearly. Perhaps you could re-word to make it clearer?

Comment: therefore the idle tasks in operating systems, so the program won't terminate. I start to remember.